# IP Failure to Connect Two Sockets on LAN over TCP (AS3, VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, actionscript-3, sockets, lan, tcp

I have a Flash AS3 client application that sends data to a VB.NET server application using TCP/IP. When testing using loopback/localhost on a single machine the data comes through. However, when I set the IPs of the sockets to the corresponding computers of the LAN  and run each application separately, there is no data reception.

VB.NET - This works:

```
Public Shared localAddress As IPAddress = IPAddress.IPv6Loopback
Public Shared port As Int32 = 8080
Public Shared server As New TcpListener(localAddress, port)
```

AS3 - This works:

```
var client : Client = new Client("localhost", 8080)
```

AS3 - This doesn't:

```
var client : Client = new Client("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 8080)
```

I have checked that the port is open (i.e. ShieldsUp returns "Stealth"). I am not sure if I should be using NetConnection instead or if I could/should set up a Flash socket policy file - both computers are running Windows.

What is the most plausible reason for no connection? Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly related (if due to Flash): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902832/as3-socketserver-sockets-connect-but-cannot-send-data-to-server-over-lan?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got a socket policy file in place? http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html

Also, set up policy file logging so you get an idea of what's going on: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ec4.html

Also, final (dumb) point: are you sure both computers are on the same network, and that the ip is right (lan ip, not public ip)?

Comment: I have only 9 months of programming experience, so not really a dumb question. Apparently, I think I was using the public IP on one of the computers (because that was what IPConfig returned); 134.*.*.* is not restricted by NIC and IANA. As I am unable to figure out the local IP (192.*, 10.*, or 172.*), maybe I could try to use the DNS names of the computers instead. I have seen the links you recommended, but alas I missed the instructions for Windows. It seems that I will have to install Cygwin and have it running on the serving computer for the scripts to work (unless I use AIR).

Comment: when you use `ipconfig`, your local ip should be the one under "IPv4 Address", and in the form `192.168...`. You shouldn't need to do anything special par rapport Windows; I work with flash sockets pretty much every day (we make multiplayer games) - once you have a xml socket policy file in place, it should be good to go. Make sure you're loading it properly - should be something like `Security.loadPolicyFile( "xmlsocket://" + ip + ":" + policyFilePort );`

Comment: For one of the computers IPConfig does not return a 192.168... address but a public one (134...). I wish to minimize memory resources on the server. Instead of installing Cygwin, would it be possible to send the file per xmlsocket:// protocol and port 843 directly through the VB NET server application?

Comment: I think I found a solution. Here is a lightweight Windows service: http://socketpolicyfile.codeplex.com/

Comment: If that works for you, go for it. Our server simply listens on port 843 and serves up the policy file as needed

Comment: I'm not sure why ipconfig isn't giving you a LAN IP for over if your computers. If they're both on the same LAN, it should work